# How to sort a dictionary inside a dictionary by values?

Tags: dictionary, sorting, lambda, nested, sorteddictionary

I am trying to sort this dictionary that contains divisions of hockey teams. Each team is an element of the dictionary and each team's value is a dictionary that has a number of points (PTS) and a VRP stat.

I'm trying to sort the teams inside each division according to their points in descending order. The sorting is independent in each division.

Here is my code:

```
dic = {
            "Atlantic": {
                "TeamA": {"PTS": 80, "VRP": 35},
                "TeamB": {"PTS": 65, "VRP": 31},
                "TeamC": {"PTS": 80, "VRP": 30}
            },
            "Metropolitan": {
                "TeamD": {"PTS": 60, "VRP": 29},
                "TeamE": {"PTS": 65, "VRP": 28}
            }
        }

def ranking_sorting(ranking):
    for division in ranking.values():
        division = dict(sorted(division.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]["PTS"], reverse = True))

ranking_sorting(dic)

print(dic)
```

I tried to use a lambda function as a key in the sorted function to access the PTS value inside the team's value with key=lambda x:[1]["PTS"].

Here is the result I expected:

```
      {
            "Atlantic": {
                "TeamA": {"PTS": 80, "VRP": 35},
                "TeamC": {"PTS": 80, "VRP": 30}
                "TeamB": {"PTS": 65, "VRP": 31},
                
            },
            "Metropolitan": {
                "TeamE": {"PTS": 65, "VRP": 28}
                "TeamD": {"PTS": 60, "VRP": 29},
                            }
        }
```

When I try to print the dictionary I get back the original one but it's not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I need to assign the "divsion" teams to the division:

```
def trier_classement(classement):
for nom_divison, equipes in classement.items():
    equipes = dict(sorted(equipes.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]["PTS"], reverse = True))
    classement[nom_divison] = equipes
```

The division teams did get sorted, but I didn't assign them to the main dictionary.